How to get an tuple of coordinates from a list inside another list
I have the following list:
list = [[0, 0, 1], 
        [1, 0, 0], 
        [0, 1, 0]]

My goal is to return from this list, a set of tuples that contain the coordinates (row, column) of each value equal to 1.
The correct answer to the above code is:
{(0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1)}

I'm working on my list comprehension knowledge. I manage to do this with a for loop and an index, but i want cleaner code. If the solution can be using list comprehension I would appreciate it

you can try this function in which you can pass the value and it will give you all the coordinates. I use list comprehaninsion.
def find_coordinates(my_list, value):
    return {(row, col) for row, sub_list in enumerate(my_list) for col, val in enumerate(sub_list) if val == value}

# Example usage:
my_list = [[0, 0, 1], 
           [1, 0, 0], 
           [0, 1, 0]]

value = 1
coordinates = find_coordinates(my_list, value)

The Output is:
{(1, 0), (0, 2), (2, 1)}


list = [[0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0]]

result = {(row_idx, col_idx) for row_idx, row in enumerate(list) for col_idx, value in enumerate(row) if value == 1}

print(result)


(Semantically) Straight forward is numpy.nonzero .
However, compared to wim's answer nonzero needs one step more as it returns rows, colums in their own sub list and it needs to be transposed to have to have individual pairs like you want.
np.transpose(np.nonzero(my_list))


Obviously what you need is a set comprehension, not a list comprehension (the syntax is the same):
my_list = [
    [0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0]
]

coordinates = {
    (row, column)
    for row in range(len(my_list))
    for column in range(len(my_list[row]))
    if my_list[row][column] == 1
}

print(coordinates)

This should print:
{(1, 0), (0, 2), (2, 1)}


You might consider using numpy for such tasks. This is essentially the argwhere function of numpy:
>>> my_list = [[0, 0, 1],
...            [1, 0, 0],
...            [0, 1, 0]]
>>> A = np.array(my_list)
>>> np.argwhere(A)
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 1]])

